# eslint does not work with app.js but works with other projects files

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint

I have a problem with eslint. It does not work with app.js in VS code(React project) but it works with other projects files ..all config files are correct and ESLint library is loaded correctly from the project folder.. **Please give me peace of advice on this issue**. Thanks in advance.

> [Info  - 11:58:44 AM] ESLint server is starting [Info  - 11:58:44 AM]
> ESLint server running in node v14.16.0 [Info  - 11:58:44 AM] ESLint
> server is running. [Info  - 11:58:45 AM] ESLint library loaded from:
> /**/**/Documents/todo/node_modules/eslint/lib/api.js

my .eslintrc.js

```
    module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'airbnb',
  ],
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
  ],
  rules: {
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [1, { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'] }],
    'react/prop-types': 'off',
  },
};
```

Comment: I think the problem is related to vscode not related to eslint

Comment: Please try this `eslint . --ext .js` command and send the results, if you getting `nothing` or something like `<count> problem` then your eslint is working fine

Comment: thanks, @NishargShah I tried `eslint . --ext .js` and got some errors in terminal ...  but I don't understand why eslint works with this file only via terminal but at the same time work perfectly with other project files.

Answer (score 0):

As I said the problem is coming from the VSCode, please refer to the documentation or Search on google `Setup Eslint in VSCode`.

I found the nice article of eslint in `dev.to`, please refer it

https://dev.to/devdammak/setting-up-eslint-in-your-javascript-project-with-vs-code-2amf

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Comment: so please consider it as an answer by click on the right arrow

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem when setup my VsCode and eslint files in my workspace (package.json and .eslintrc.js) like in this nice article ["Setup ESLint for React with Prettier, pre-commit and VSCode"](https://www.inkoop.io/blog/setup-eslint-for-react-with-prettier-pre-commit-and-vscode/)

thanks for helping